# How i can fix ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' Error

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I ran into a problem, I need Jitsi Meet and DartSIPUa in the project, but when I put them together it gives a duplicate error, I attached the log below. Can you also explain to me why my Flutter project that has JitsiMeet uses react-native-webrtc?
I tried for a long time to find what the reason might be, as long as JitsiMeet works separately from DartSIPUa, everything is fine, but I need them in one app, how can I do this?
Thank you all in advance for your help.

Log: https://pastebin.com/2RT30qEs

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder found in modules classes.jar (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28262) and libwebrtc.jar (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.75.3-jitsi-4429568)
  Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$1 found in modules classes.jar (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28262) and libwebrtc.jar (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.75.3-jitsi-4429568)
```

Answer (score 0):

found a [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49938#issuecomment-581080836)

TLDR

I solved the two above problems as following:
First problem (:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses)
solution was: Through android studio
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...

Second problem (:app:mergeDebugJavaResource)

The solution was:
Due to the generated build file path exceeds the windows max path length of 255 characters.
Only trying to use short names to make sure the project path is not too long, solved the problem.

This is the path in my machine:
C:\Users\Hakim.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_64_debug\1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119\1ae520cbbf7e14af867232784194366b3d1c3f34\x86_64_debug-1.0.0-a67792536ca236a971d0efbcfd7af4efb8f6c119.jar

You can find the path in your machine and change the long file name to short one.

else try downgrading your flutter version

Comment: It didn't help me.
I don't understand why Jitsi for Flutter uses react-native-web-rtc and where to find it, since there is no mention of it in the Jitsi files.

Comment: maybe on of your packages does

Comment: I checked all the files and libraries in my flutter project